# Resolve - Capture email from WooCommerce Register Form to Mailchimp

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I have default WooCommerce Registration form for user. I want to capture email from this form to Mailchimp.

Here is registration form code.

```
<!-- Register Form -->

<form method="post" class="register">

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

        <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="reg_password"><?php _e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" />
        </p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>
    <?php do_action( 'register_form' ); ?>

    <p class="form-row">
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register' ); ?>
        <input type="submit" class="button small" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>
</form>
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Download, install and activate the [MailChimp plugin for Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/).

2) Go to MailChimp for WP -> Integrations in the Wordpress admin.

3) Activate the Custom integration.

4) Add the HTML of the Custom integration to your WooCommerce form.

5) MailChimp will do the rest.